# Experiencing issues with custom mine_functions in saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

I want to add a mine function that gets the hostname of a minion.

`pillar/custom.sls`

```
mine_functions:
  custom:
    - mine_function: grains.get
    - nodename
```

I manually refresh the pillar data by running a 
`salt '*' saltutil.refresh_pillar`

and when running `salt '*' mine.get '*' custom` the output is as expected, showing a list of minions all with the nodename data underneath.

The issue is when I try to do thew following in a template file:

```
{%- set custom_nodes = [] %}
bootstrap.servers={% for host, custom in salt['mine.get']('role:foo', 'custom', expr_form='grain').items() %}
  {% do hosts.append(custom + ':2181') %}
{% endfor %}{{ custom_nodes|join(',') }}
```

I just get an empty space where my list of server nodenames should be.

I was hoping someone might be able to point out where I'm going wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are appending the list to `hosts` but then using `custom_nodes` with the join?

Was this on purpose?

I think what you actually want is

```
{%- set custom_nodes = [] %}
bootstrap.servers={% for host, custom in salt['mine.get']('role:foo', 'custom', expr_form='grain').items() %}
  {% do custom_nodes.append(custom + ':2181') %}
{% endfor %}{{ custom_nodes|join(',') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

`pillar/custom.sls`

```
mine_functions:
  id_list:
    mine_function: grains.get
    key : nodename
```

`templete.sls`

```
{% for server in salt['mine.get']('*', 'id_list') | dictsort() %}
server {{ server }} {{ addrs[0] }}:80 check
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was quite simple. I was unaware one needed to restart existing minions before they could access the mine data.